# How to show specific word from a specific line?

Tags: sed, grep, cat

let say I have a text file and I want to show echo from it only the 3rd word in the 48th line, how can I do it?

I was able to show a specific line from the text file:

```
sed -n 48p log.txt
```

but now I need to find a way to show only the 3rd word...

Comment: You can use `awk` - `awk 'NR == 48 { print $3 }'`

Comment: thanks, but I dont understand where do I inset the name of the text file?

Comment: At the last `awk 'NR == 48 { print $3 }' file`

Comment: thank you very much, it's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sed -n 48p log.txt | cut -d' ' -f3
```

Answer (score 0):

Gets convoluted to do in only sed:

`sed -En '48{s/(\s*\S+\s*){2}//;s/\s+.*//;p}'`

Delete the first two words, then delete everything except the remaining first word, then print.